# Can we update a TFS label with the changes made for **files** based on the change set number

Tags: tfs

Can we update a label with  the changes made for **files** based on the change set number?

Say I have checked in 2 files, currently i am opening the label adding the individual files.

Is there a way to update the label in a single shot, based on the change set number?